What does it say in the inscriptions on Benjamin's doorway; A Canticle for Leibowitz
I'm looking to see if the following are correct translations from A Canticle for Leibowitz. Miller used a couple of languages in his novel and sometimes translates them in the text, especially with the Latin passages.
In Fiat Lux, The Abbot Paulo visits the hermit Benjamin. When he does so, he notices an inscription on a stone outside Benjamin's doorway that looks like this:

He is then invited to look on the other side of the stone:

"All right, doubt me. But if you don't believe what's written there, you can't be expected to believe what's written on the other side of the sign."

He looks and makes out another inscription:

Both are in Hebrew.
For the first, the accompanying text says:

The size of the sign, and its apparent attempt to advertise, led Abbot Paulo to grin and ask: "What does it say, Benjamin? Does it attract much trade up here?"
"Hah - what should it say? It says: Tents mended here."
The priest snorted his disbelief.

For the second:

The priest sighed. "All right, Benjamin, I know what it was that you were commanded to write 'in the entry and on the door' of your house. But only you would think of turning it face down."

For the first, I used google Translate with the phrase "Tents mended here" and Hebrew selected for the translation. The first word in the book looks like the last in Translate, but none of the other two match. I'm aware that Hebrew is written right-to-left, so first -> last in Translate might make sense as I don't think Translate is that subtle, or even likely to be correct, but I have no better method of translation available to me.
This might mean that the second is a Mezuzah, but none of the texts for these that I could see looked like the text in the book.
So, is the translation on the first correct as "tents mended here" and what does the second say?

Google Lens translates the first as "They set up tents here", and the second as "Hear Israel, Jehovah our God, Jehovah Ehad".  I don't know Hebrew, and have not read this book, so i don't know if the translations makes any sense?

The second is the Shma, and is generally translated as Hear, O Israel: The Lord is G-d; the Lord is One. In transliterated Hebrew, Shma Yisrael «hashem» «elocanu» «hashem» echad. «hashem» and «elocanu» are standard substitutions for the actual words - the first being His Name, the second being His Title - when transliterating in a non-Holy context.

Not important, but I would have said/transliterated <> ("Lord") for YHVH rather than <> ("the name") . (Non-practicing Ashkenazi Jew here.) And <> is not a substitution, but the actual transliteration, for  אלהינו

@BenBolker - I was taught not to use «ad-n--» in non-Holy contexts, and to substitute «hashem»; similarly with «elo--nu», with the H, vs. «elocanu» with the hard C/K.

OK, fair enough.

If it helps, I think the sets of letters are: ‘פה מתקנין אוהלים’ and ‘שמע ישראל יהוה אלהינו יהוה אחד’.  (Disclaimer: I know no Hebrew; that was mostly Google's work.)

@JeffZeitlin Thanks. I knew there would be someone on here who could read Hebrew. I'd not come across the Shma before, but Wikipedia has the same translation as yours (without the redactions for the Name).

The first says something like "There they set up tents" - possibly the intended meaning is "Tents installed here".
The second is a Hebrew prayer: "Hear O Israel, the Lord is our God, the Lord is One". This is the first line of what is known as the Shema, the most important prayer in the Jewish religion.
The first paragraph of that prayer ends with the words "And you shall write them [ie, these words] upon the doorposts of your home, and at your gates", which is the origin of the mezuzah.
It's been a long time since I read Canticle though so I'm not sure of the relevance of the first quote.

It's surprising for me to see the Shema referred to repeatedly as a "prayer" (see also Ben Bolker's comment). In my understanding, a prayer is an act of speaking to God (or some deity). Whereas the Shema is spoken by Moses, passing on the words (including commands) of God, to the people of Israel.

Thanks. Benjamin in Canticle is a metaphor for the biblical Israelites who are the "light" trying to preserve and advance knowledge after the downfall of man. He's more or less immortal in the book and features in all 3 sections despite 1000's of years time difference.  I'm not sure why the tents are mentioned though

@LarsH In traditional Judaism, the Shema is a prayer that was written by Moses in the Torah and which is: (a) placed in the Mezuzah on doorposts, (b) inside Tefilin (phylacteries) - leather boxes with parchment inside worn by men during morning prayers and (c) recited twice a day as part of prayer services. It is one of the very few spoken items/prayers (as opposed to "actions") commanded in the Torah and is the only one that is actually written in the Torah, though various other sections (generally much smaller than the 3 paragraphs of the Shema) are quoted as part of many other prayers.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Thanks. I guess it's just an unusual usage of the word "prayer." Wikipedia calls the Shema a "prayer" too. Whereas the definitions at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prayer don't seem to fit. But this is a digression.

The priest's comment

"All right, Benjamin, I know what it was that you were commanded to
write 'in the entry and on the door' of your house. But only you would
think of turning it face down."

is a reference to a Mezuzah

In the biblical verses where the mezuzah command is found, the purpose
is educational, to constantly remind a person of God's commandments:
And these words, which I command thee this day, shall be upon thy heart; and thou shalt teach them diligently unto thy children, and
shalt talk of them when thou sittest in thy house, and when thou
walkest by the way, and when thou liest down, and when thou risest up.
And thou shalt bind them for a sign upon thy hand, and they shall be
for frontlets between thine eyes. And thou shalt write them upon the
door-posts of thy house, and upon thy gates

so the second Hebrew phrase is probably some version of the Mezuzah inscription.

"The mezuzah opens up and inside is the Shema prayer, written on a small piece of parchment."  https://jewishmuseum.org.uk/schools/asset/rabbi-ron-berry-explains-the-shema/ (See @DanielRoseman's answer for further details)
